# upload base64 image with WCF service

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, wcf

I creat WCF service to Upload my image from device to server.
when I goto this address http://XXXXXXXXXX.com/WebService.asmx and Insert base64 string to textbox and Invoke it's right and my base64 image converted to image and save in data base. but when I use the Swift Code it doesn't Without any error !!
my code in wift :

```
func uploadImage(image:String) {
    act.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    let url_to_request = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld"

    let myurl:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myurl)
    request.HTTPMethod="POST"
    let postString = "base64=\(image)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            if error != nil {
                print("error : \(error)")
                self.messageshow3()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                self.act.stopAnimating()
                return
            }

            do {
                if let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as? NSDictionary
                {
                    print(jsonData)


                    let mess = jsonData["IsAdded"] as! String

                    if mess == "ok" {

                    }

                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                self.act.stopAnimating()
                print(error)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I use this function everywhere and works Good. but here make problem and I'm confused.

this is a bas64 String that when I copy in in textBox and manually Invoke works good.but when In use in input of upper function nothing happen.
Thanks.

sample base64 :

```
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
```

Comment: Can you log what the server receives?

Comment: @PaulPeelen how can do this ? I'm sure the righ string POST to server

Comment: Well, I don't know what web service you are using so I can't tell you that. However, If you are not using any web service you control yourself or cannot log for any reason you could try using [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to proxy and log the request. That way you can see what is actually send.

Comment: @PaulPeelen I use charles in MAC and see the output . the method was POST and see the POST String it was correct.

Comment: Is that any limitation about POST in info.plist ???

Comment: @PaulPeelen I Found something  deference between manually POST and POST in postString in charles.
in manually POST and invoke it convert all the '/' to %2F and all '=' to %3D in base64 type and when i COpy this new poststring in my app it's work !!.

Comment: Ok, that is URLencoding you are talking about. In such case, URLencode it first, and then make the call again. `var escapedString = image.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())`

Comment: @PaulPeelen thanks very Much. your comment about install charles help me very much.thanks